# When an object can't really be `null` in a particular screen

Tags: typescript, react-native

We have a React Native app that uses Redux and we've just converted most of it from Javascript to Typescript. I'm new new to Typescript so bear with me here.

As simply as i can, here's an explanation of the problem. There are two screens: `SignIn` and `Settings` (not our real screens but it gets the point across).

In the Redux state, there's an object:

```js
user: {
    // Whatever user properties we store, id etc
}
```

When a user signs in, `user` is set. Until then, it's `null`, so `user: User | null`.

We use `createSelector` from `reselect` to fetch the user.
The user is fetched on the Settings page and it can technically be `null` if the user has managed to navigate there without signing in, though this isn't a real use case. To reach the `Settings` page, you have to sign in. And when you sign in, the `user` can no longer be `null`.

In the `Settings` page, when accessing e.g. `user.id`, `tsc` says:

> error TS2531: Object is possibly 'null'

How should this be handled? Is there a way to tell Typescript (or `tsc`, really) that there's no way `user` can be `null` on this particular screen? Or should we add a check in each screen making sure `user` isn't null (even though *it shouldn't be possible®*)?

I prefer not to suppress the typescript error, if at all possible.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [non-null assertion operator: `!`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#non-null-assertion-operator)

For example, if you say:

```
const user = useSelector(state => state.somewhere.user)

<Text>
  {user!.name}
</Text>
```

Without the `!` at the end of the name `user`, typescript recognizes that this can be null, and you can't call `null.name`, so TypeScript errors.  However, if you say `user!.name`, you are telling TypeScript that you *know* in this scenario it will *not* be `null`.

Note that many linters will yell at you, because this is a somewhat unsafe practice.  If you have any concern at all, write checks to make sure its not really null.  If you're 100% beyond-any-doubt sure it will exist when called, the non-null assertion operator is fine.  I use it all the time.

Comment: I think that's it, looks like a good solution. Thank you very much.